# response.sendRedirect() is not redirecting and does not throw any error

Tags: java, redirect, servlets

I try to develop a voice controlled web application. The problem is that it is not redirecting to the existing Webservlets url and does not shown any error messages.
Here is my doPost method in my Controller.java file: (in the second 'if' the redirect works fine, only in the third is not working.)

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    HttpSession session = req.getSession();

    if (req.getParameter("productId") != null){
        int prodID = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("productId"));
        cartHandler.add(prodID);
    }
    // LOGOUT
    if(req.getParameter("btn-logout") != null){
        if(session.getAttribute("uID") != null) {
            session.removeAttribute("uID");
            resp.sendRedirect("/");
        }
    }

    if(req.getParameter("allieStart") != null){
        String greeting = allieDaoJDBC.getAnswer("greeting");
        playSound.play(greeting);
        Integer react = speechRecognition.listen(allieDaoJDBC, cartHandler);
        if(react == 1){
            resp.sendRedirect("/cart");
        }else if(react == 2){
            resp.sendRedirect("/login");
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: What's the value of the "allieStart" request param?

Comment: `data: { allieStart : " "}` an empty string, because I dont want to send any data via  AJAX. If I print out the value of the react variable, it returns the expected value and goes into the proper if condition.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure `allieStart` is not null, then the problem must be with `react`
(i.e. react is not 1 or 2.) Try adding another else condition, so you can be sure **something will happen.**

```
    if(react == 1){
        resp.sendRedirect("/cart");
    }else if(react == 2){
        resp.sendRedirect("/login");
    }else{
        resp.sendRedirect("/login");
    }
```

Comment: If I print out the value of the react variable, it returns the expected value and goes into the proper if condition.

Comment: then what is your problem?

Comment: or what do you mean by "if you print it out, it works"

Comment: If I print out the reacts value in the if condition. It just doesnt redirect to the given webservlet url.

Comment: with a normal `system.out.print` ?

Comment: Yes, with that.

Comment: hmm, that's very strange. Could you show me in teamviewer?